# Не проходит оплата в боте telegram aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

```
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
uc = UserCallBack(token, con, cur)


@dp.pre_checkout_query_handler(lambda query: True)
async def pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_q: types.PreCheckoutQuery):
    await bot.answer_pre_checkout_query(pre_checkout_q.id, ok=True)


@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentType.SUCCESSFUL_PAYMENT)
async def successful():
    print(23)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.send_invoice(chat_id=message.chat.id,
                           title="Оплата подписки",
                           description="Оплата подписки в боте",
                           payload="sub",
                           provider_token="381764678:TEST:66266",
                           currency="RUB",
                           is_flexible=False,
                           start_parameter="one_month_sub",
                           prices=[{"label": "Руб", "amount": 20000}])

executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Инвойс создается, форма открывается, но в итоге выходит BOT_PRECHECKOUT_TIMEOUT после ввода данных карты. [image: скрин]

Не знаю что делать, пол гугла облазил уже, да и раньше всё нормально работало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в самом боте, а не в коде. Создал нового и всё заработало